# DJI Spark: missing support for FlightController.setMaxFlightHeight() FlightController.setMaxFlightRadius()

Tags: android, dji-sdk

According to DJI Mobile SDK Documentation one can set the maximum allowed flight height and flight radius for waypoint missions using

```
FlightController.setMaxFlightHeight([20,500])
FlightController.setMaxFlightRadius(15,8000])
```

https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/android-api/Components/FlightController/DJIFlightController.html?search=maxflight&i=4&#djiflightlimitation_setmaxflightradius_inline

This works well for all drones apart from DJI Spark which throws the following error:

```
Failed to set max altitude, Param illegal
```

My questions: 
 1. Are these limits not supported by the SDK for the DJI Spark? If so, the documentation should be updated accordingly.
 2. Is there another way DJI provides limits for Waypoints mission for the DJI Spark, that I am not aware of?

Comment: Same problem here, still no solution right?!

Answer (score 0):

for spark the range of maxFlightHeight is [20,50]

Comment: This does not seem to be true:  
a) SDK documentation does not confirm it.  
b) DJI go 4 allows to change for spark in range [20,500] (although that value seems not to be pushed properly to the drone, as it is not stored)  
c) In automated missions you can fly higher than 50 meters with Drone Harmony.  
You might refer to flying without a remote controller which is a completely different thing, as you rely on the on board WiFi connection.